# Check if any overlapping hours in a list

Tags: scala

I have a list of opening hours for each day which is of type

```
Map[String, List[(String, String)]]
```

Key is the day of the week and the list elements contain Open_from and open_to. Below is the sample example

```
Map(MONDAY -> List( (08:00:00, 12:00:00), (13:00:00, 16:00:00)), 
    TUESDAY -> List( (09:00:00, 12:00:00), (13:00:00, 16:00:00)),
  ...
  ...
)
```

I have to check the below conditions to check if there are any overlapping hours

1. Open_to should be greater than Open_from
2. If there is more than 1 element in list for a day (as in the above example) then open_to from the first element should be less than open_from of next element.

Have to return true or false if there are any overlapping hours in that Map. I tried doing with foldLeft and compare with next element in the list. But wasnt sure how to return the boolean value.

Could you please let me know how can this be done. Thanks

THanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you were on the right path with the foldLeft. I used Int's in my implementation instead of times. There's a lot of room for improvement regarding readability:

```
val openingTimes = Map(
    "MONDAY" -> List( (1, 2), (3, 4)), 
    "TUESDAY" -> List( (1, 3), (2, 4))
)

openingTimes.forall { case (_, timeRanges) =>
  timeRanges.forall { case (from, to) => from < to } &&
    timeRanges.foldLeft(true -> Int.MinValue) { case ((nonOverlapping, prevTime), (time)) =>
      (nonOverlapping && prevTime < time._1) -> time._2
    }._1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `foldLeft` for this. Something like this should work to check both conditions:

```
val isValid = ranges
  .iterator
  .flatMap { case (a,b) => Seq(a, b) }
  .sliding(2)
  .forall { case Seq(a,b) => a < b }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution, I think an important piece other solutions are missing is assuming the time blocks are ordered, which may not be the case:

```scala
val validSchedule = Map("MONDAY" -> List((8, 12), (13, 16)), 
    "TUESDAY" -> List( (9, 12), (13, 16)),
)
val validUnorderedSchedule = Map("MONDAY" -> List((8, 12), (13, 16)), 
    "TUESDAY" -> List( (9, 12), (13, 16)),
    "WEDNESDAY" -> List((9, 12), (14, 15), (6, 7)), // (6,7) comes after (14,15), but is still valid
)
val invalidSchedule = Map("MONDAY" -> List((8, 12), (13, 16)), 
    "TUESDAY" -> List( (9, 12), (11, 16)),
)
val invalidUnorderedSchedule = Map("MONDAY" -> List((8, 12), (13, 16)), 
    "TUESDAY" -> List((9, 12), (11, 16)),
    "WEDNESDAY" -> List((9, 12), (14, 15), (7, 10)), // (7,10) overlaps with (9,12)
)

def validateSingleTimeBlock(timeBlock: (Int, Int)): Boolean = timeBlock._1 <= timeBlock._2
def validateConsecutiveTimeBlocks(first: (Int, Int), second: (Int, Int)): Boolean = first._2 <= second._1
def combineValidatedTimeBlocks(first: (Int, Int), second: (Int, Int)): (Int, Int) = (first._1, second._2)

def validateSchedule(schedule: Map[String, List[(Int, Int)]]): Boolean = {
  schedule.values
    .map { timeBlocksForDay => timeBlocksForDay.sortBy { _(0) } }  // for each day, order time blocks by opening time
    .forall { timeBlocksForDay =>
        timeBlocksForDay.foldLeft(true -> (Option.empty[(Int, Int)])) { // for each day, we'll reduce the list of time blocks to a pair that represents if the day so far is valid, and if so, what hours have been covered already
          case ((validSoFar, timesAlreadyScheduled), nextTimeBlock) if validSoFar =>
            val validatedTimeBlock = Some(nextTimeBlock) filter (validateSingleTimeBlock)
            val next = (timesAlreadyScheduled, validatedTimeBlock) match {
              case (Some(prev), n) =>
                n filter (validateConsecutiveTimeBlocks(prev, _)) map (combineValidatedTimeBlocks(prev, _)) 
              case (None, n) => n // the first time block we've seen for the day
            }
            (next.isDefined, next)
          case _ => (false, None)
        }._1
    }
}

println(validateSchedule(validSchedule)) // true
println(validateSchedule(invalidSchedule)) // false
println(validateSchedule(validUnorderedSchedule)) // true
println(validateSchedule(invalidUnorderedSchedule)) // false
```

Here's a runnable scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Gmia1WsnSqGbbZgTJKWoYw